# How to click a button post 5 seconds after entering data in selenium web driver using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, callback, promise

I have a payment page where I enter my card details and click on "Pay" button. But when I use selenium web driver with node.js, my button gets clicked very fast even before the data is entered and I get my mandatory field validations. Below is my code.I tried driver.sleep but, it didn't work.How can I wait for 2 or 3 seconds after my data are entered before clicking the button. Please adise.

```
    var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
        By = webdriver.By,
        until = webdriver.until;

    var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .build();

    //calling enterCardDetails function
    enterCardDetails(driver);

   //function to enter card details
    function enterCardDetails(driver) {

    driver.get('https://pp.eshapay.net/THREER/pages/paypage.jsf?transref=86ffeef6-0f2b-45bb-9dd6-a5e210dad1b6&store=100017');

    driver.wait(
        until.elementLocated(By.id('paymentDetailsTitle')), 
        20000
      );

      driver.findElement(By.id('cardholderName')).sendKeys('johny');
      driver.findElement(By.id('cardNumber')).sendKeys('4444333322221111');


      driver.wait(
        until.elementLocated(By.id("expiryMonth")), 20000
    ).then(element => {
        selectFromDropdown(element, "02")
    });

    //function to select value from dropdown
    function selectFromDropdown(select, textDesired) {
        select.findElements(By.tagName('option'))
        .then(options => {
            options.map(option => {
                option.getText().then(text => {
                    if (text == textDesired)
                        option.click();
                });
            });
        });
    }

    driver.wait(
        until.elementLocated(By.id("expiryYear")), 20000
    ).then(element => {
        selectFromDropdown(element, "2020")
    });

    driver.findElement(By.id('csc')).sendKeys('123');

    }
//driver.findElement(By.id('btnSubmit')).click();
```

Comment: have you tried using javascript to click the element?

Answer (score 0):

Either go for Thread.sleep(5000) which i won't recommend or before clicking on Pay button try to fetch the value from card details textbox check if it is not empty then click on Pay button.